# Python setuptools LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file "C:\Program.obj"

Tags: python, c++, setuptools

I'm trying to compile a  C++ code for Python:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension

setup(
    ext_modules=[Extension('sum', ['main.cpp'],),],
)
```

When building it I get this error:

> `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file "C:\Program.obj"`

I think that this is caused because of spaces in path to needed .obj file. Is there any way to fix it?

If this will help here is my C++ test code:

```
extern "C"

int sum(int a, int b){
    int sum = 0;
    sum = a + b;

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: How are you doing the build? That error means there is a path being added to the link

Comment: I'm just using python script via `python setup.py build`.